# swipe or dragfromtoforduration in WDA takes too much time

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios

I was using the newest wda to control iphone real device.
xcode version9.3
iPhone 6s, iOS 11.2.6
Launched wda by xcode and control command was send out by my python client.

```
data = dict(fromX=x1, fromY=y1, toX=x2, toY=y2, duration=duration) 
self.http.post('/wda/dragfromtoforduration', data=data)
```

and for example swipe from left to right takes about 5 seconds. Is this time reasonable or is there anything wrong?
Here is the xcode log of one single swipe anction:

> t = 1431.73s Find the Application "com.apple.springboard" 0x10561bd50
>
> t = 1431.73s Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 56
>
> t = 1431.95s Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 56
>
> t = 1432.05s Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 56
>
> t = 1432.18s Find the Window
>
> t = 1432.18s Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 56
>
> t = 1432.33s Find the Window
>
> t = 1432.33s Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 56
>
> t = 1432.48s Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 56
>
> t = 1432.60s Find the Window
>
> t = 1432.60s Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 56
>
> t = 1432.74s Find the Window
>
> t = 1432.74s Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 56
>
> t = 1432.92s Press and drag from Window[0.00, 0.00] -> (0.0, 333.0) to
>   Window[0.00, 0.00] -> (375.0, 333.0)
>
> t = 1432.92s Wait for com.apple.springboard to idle
>
> t = 1432.94s Find the Window
>
> t = 1432.94s Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 56
>
> t = 1433.18s Synthesize event
>
> t = 1433.21s Find the Window
>
> t = 1433.21s Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 56
>
> t = 1433.38s Find the Window
>
> t = 1433.39s Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 56
>
> t = 1435.08s Wait for com.apple.springboard to idle

Comment: What's the duration parameter value you are passing?

Comment: i did not set this parameter, so it's the default value 0.